# Range of hashcodes in case of strings

Tags: java, netbeans, hashcode

I have strings coming in my code and i take hashcode of them for some purpose but i was wondering that is there any range of these hashcodes because this may happen that the number of strings coming exceed the range of hashcodes.So what is the range of hashcodes?

Comment: The Range of hashCodes is Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE. and yes, most of the strings hascodes will be duplicated. Pigeon hole principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range of `hashCode` is the range of `int`.  For any desired `hashCode()`, there is a `String` with that `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

The `hashCode` method for `String` class in java is defined like this...

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                h = 31*h + val[off++];
            }
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
```

It will always have some value for your String.....So, i don;t think you will ever run out of hashCode's...